# how to retrospectively adjust columns in Pandas so it loops through and adjusts the subsquent columns

Tags: python, pandas, loops, stock, rolling-computation

thanks in advance. apologies for the awful title i couldnt work out how to put it into words

i currently have a program writtin in python with Pandas that goes through stock data and tests my trading strategy. i was looking to expand on the complexity but i have hit a road block. i ahve it set up to return a 1 in the purchase column after my buy signal is generated. it returns a 1 in the sell column when a sell signal is generated. absed on these numbers the hold cumn tracks how long i've held the share for and gives a -1 when the share sells. the changes column keeps track of the fluctation in share price while trades are active.

which brings me to my question. i would like the sell signal to return a 1 when the sum of the changes during a trade exceeds 2*ATR. i currently cant work out how to get a rolling sum of the changes column over just the active periods and i dont know how to retrospectively adjust the sell column the then properly assess the strategy.

tldr: how do i get a rolling sum over a variable period and how can i feed this into a previously generated column to re-adjust the trade

```
       Date      Purchase  Sell_Check  Hold     ATR   Changes
162  20190821         0           1     0  0.050429  0.000000
163  20190822         1           0     0  0.048834  0.000000
164  20190823         0           0     1  0.048686 -0.010484
165  20190826         0           1     1  0.050159 -0.022005
166  20190827         1           0    -1  0.048226 -0.027083
167  20190828         0           0     1  0.046424  0.093158
168  20190829         0           0     1  0.046783  0.047383
169  20190830         0           0     1  0.044983  0.045915
170  20190902         0           0     1  0.043924  0.012912
171  20190903         0           0     1  0.041378  0.017527
172  20190904         0           0     1  0.039872 -0.003758
173  20190905         0           0     1  0.039173  0.023577
174  20190906         0           0     1  0.038237  0.040541
175  20190909         0           0     1  0.037025 -0.000295
176  20190910         0           0     1  0.039986 -0.041335
177  20190911         0           1     1  0.041945 -0.011395
178  20190912         0           0    -1  0.042984 -0.014953
179  20190913         0           0     0  0.041245  0.000000
180  20190916         0           0     0  0.041138  0.000000
181  20190917         0           1     0  0.041588  0.000000
182  20190918         0           0     0  0.041113  0.000000
183  20190919         0           0     0  0.039908  0.000000
184  20190920         0           0     0  0.039572  0.000000
```

Comment: I assume that everytime the value of "Changes" change, you have to add the current value and new value and store it in a new column and when this new column value exceeds 2*ATR you have to set "sell" column value =1. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: that is correct